# How to trigger Slack notifications as a Validation Action in Great_Expectations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have the following Great_Expectation in Apache Spark with Databricks and Synapse on Apache Spark

```
ge_df.expect_column_values_to_be_between('load_id', min_value=1000, max_value=1049).
```

I have tried to add a slack notification to the Great_Expectation as follows:

```
ge_df.expect_column_values_to_be_between('load_id', min_value=1000, max_value=1049, slack_render = {"text": (test information,['MY_SLACK_WEBHOOK'])
```

But it fails

Can someone let me know where I might be going wrong?

I also tried the following, but it was a little too advanced for me:

````
if not validation_results["success"]:
    num_evaluated = validation_results["statistics"]["evaluated_expectations"]
    num_successful = validation_results["statistics"]["successful_expectations"]
    validation_results_text = json.dumps(
        [result.to_json_dict() for result in validation_results["results"]],
        sort_keys=True,
        indent=4,
    )
    slack_renderer = {
        "text": (
            f"⚠️ Dataset has failed expecations\n"
            f"*Successful Expectations*: `{num_successful}/{num_evaluated}`\n"
            f"*Results*: ```\n{validation_results_text}\n```"
        )
    }

    response = requests.post(
        os.environ['SLACK_WEBHOOK'],
        data=json.dumps(slack_renderer),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    )
````

I get the error when I enter slack_webhook

```
KeyError: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1L0WSW9F/B028H2KKPU3/56EZfTdU1oIprsrxxx'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1L0WSW9F/B028H2KKPU3/56EZfTdU1oIprsrxxx'
```

I believe the problem is here:

```
response = requests.post(
        os.environ['https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'],
        data=json.dumps(slack_renderer),
        headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    )
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried importing the following module ```from great_expectations.checkpoint.actions.validate.slack_renderer``` but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by change the requests.post to

```
response = requests.post(
    webhook_url, data=json.dumps(slack_renderer),
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    )
```